# Updating slickgrid autocomplete fields without rerendering the grid

Tags: autocomplete, slickgrid

I'm using SlickGrid in a sharepoint environment to display and update data. To save on the the load time, I am populating auto complete fields with options that have only been used in previous lines (with tables with more than 50 lines), and then I am wanting to give the user the option to click on a "Metadata refresh button" located at the top of the autocomplete fields that will go and fetch all available options to repopulate the auto complete field.

```html
<table><tr><td>[ TextField ] </td><td>[ AutoComplete1 ] </td><td>[ AutoComplete2]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry1</td><td>Hello</td><td>Goodbye</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry2</td><td>Hi</td><td>Later</td></tr>
</table>
```

So if, the user was to create a new line, they would have the options of Hello and Hi in column 2, and Goodbye or Later in column 3 to choose from since they have been used before. If they want the option "Hail!" to appear in column 2, they would have to click the "Update MetaData" button for column 2, which would refresh ALL the cells in that column with all available but previously unused selections.

I know its not ideal, but its a requirement that has been given to me.

I know how to add buttons to column headers and I am updating the array of data that the grid needs for the autocomplete column, but I am at a loss on how to update the column choices without redrawing the whole grid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the newer examples in my repo: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples

This is probably closest to what you want:
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-autocomplete-editor.html

What I have done in the past is create a data property of the cell node to store the object, like:

```
$jqacContainer.data('queryautocomplete', jqac);
```

It's then easy enough to get the object from the cell node.
However, this requires proper cleanup of the property to avoid a memory leak. This should be able to be done in `editor.destroy()`, but I don't think I've checked corner cases, for example where the editor is scrolled offscreen before being completed.